# Colocar item invisivel e outro ficar no lugar

Tags: android

Tenho um `RadioGroup` e um botão embaixo dele, mais este botão fica invisível ate um certo momento, tem como eu fazer o `RadioGroup` ocupar o espaço em branco enquanto o botão esta invisível ?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Coloque esse botão com a seguinte propriedade no xml:

```
android:visibility="gone"
```

Quando esse botão tiver que ser exibido, você deve fazer via código:

```
botao.setVisibility(Button.VSIBLE);
```